# Why Flink uses the Pushgateway instead of Prometheus's usual pull model for general metrics collection?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, prometheus-pushgateway

We can see Flink uses the Pushgateway instead of Prometheus's usual pull model for general metrics collection when  exposing Flink Metrics to an external system such as Prometheus.

```java
@Override
public void report() {
    try {
        pushGateway.push(CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry, jobName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Failed to push metrics to PushGateway with jobName {}.", jobName, e);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-metrics/flink-metrics-prometheus/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/metrics/prometheus/PrometheusPushGatewayReporter.java

however from the Prometheus's official document below it states that "Prometheus scrapes metrics from instrumented jobs, either directly or via an intermediary push gateway for ***short-lived jobs***" , obviously Flink Streaming job is not short-lived jobs, so why Flink uses the Pushgateway instead of Prometheus's usual pull model for general metrics collection?

https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink offers both the [PrometheusPushGatewayReporter](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/monitoring/metrics.html#prometheuspushgateway-orgapacheflinkmetricsprometheusprometheuspushgatewayreporter) and the generally more appropriate pull-based [PrometheusReporter](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/monitoring/metrics.html#prometheus-orgapacheflinkmetricsprometheusprometheusreporter). Prometheus has become quite popular with Flink users, and there was interest in the community in supporting both types of connection.

Comment: David,may I know which flink metrics are suitable for PrometheusReporter and others metrics  are more suitable for  PrometheusPushGatewayReporter ?

Comment: I believe the motivating use case involved running Flink in yarn-cluster mode, in which case it's difficult to point prometheus to the appropriate job manager. Pushing is much easier. I don't see it being a question of which metrics are better suited for push vs pull, but rather about the characteristics of the job or the deployment model.

Comment: Can you kindly help to check this issue ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962849/how-to-export-flink-task-or-back-pressure-related-metrics-to-prometheus